# }catch (ex){} showing in header

Tags: plugins, plugin-mailchimp

I have this string showing in the header of my site :
}catch (ex){}

I can see this in the source code :

```
    }</style><script>try{ <script id="mcjs">!function(c,h,i,m,p){m=c.createElement(h),p=c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0],m.async=1,m.src=i,p.parentNode.insertBefore(m,p)}(document,"script","https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/2095bd42340716fa509260a90/406ca4747992260e47dbadffd.js");</script>
 }catch (ex){}</script>     <style type="text/css" id="wp-custom-css">
            @media (max-width: 465px){
    .heading-mobile-center{
        text-align: center;
    }
```

Can anyone help ?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, you need to remove that `}catch (ex){}` part. Is this coming from a plugin? Then you should talk to their support. If not, please show the code how this gets generated.

Comment: Looks like it comes from MailChimp - if you use their plugin, open a ticket on their support forum.

Answer (score 2):

You have nested *<script>* tags in your snippet. Try the following snippet, it's reformatted for readability:

```js
    <script id="mcjs">
    try {
        ! function(c, h, i, m, p) {
            m = c.createElement(h), p = c.getElementsByTagName(h)[0], m.async = 1, m.src = i, p.parentNode.insertBefore(m, p)
        }(document, "script", "https://chimpstatic.com/mcjs-connected/js/users/2095bd42340716fa509260a90/406ca4747992260e47dbadffd.js");
    } catch (ex) {}
    </script>
```